# A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences_linux'

Tags: flutter

When I add a dependency   shared_preferences: ^0.5.8

- Where:
  Script 'D:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 362
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences_linux'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':path_provider_linux'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

pubspec.ymal

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

You must show the pubspec.yaml file

Comment: @nick when you write the command `flutter pub get` the result is okay?

Comment: @nick when problem and errors with `project ':path_provider_linux']` is show?

Answer (score 0):

he problem has been solved, The reason is that the SDK version is too low, v1,12.13+h9  update to  1.17.5